# Error bad formatted XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, apache-cocoon

I want to transform a html to xml, performing transformation XSLT, but I see this error:

```
<message>
Impossible to read XSLT from 'file:/home/antonmm/src/cardMarket/cocoon-cardmarket/src/main/resources/COB-INF/xsl/productCard.xsl', see nested exception
</message>
<stacktrace>
org.apache.cocoon.pipeline.SetupException: Impossible to read XSLT from 'file:/home/antonmm/src/cardMarket/cocoon-cardmarket/src/main/resources/COB-INF/xsl/productCard.xsl', see nested exception at org.apache.cocoon.sax.component.XSLTTransformer.loadXSLT(XSLTTransformer.java:168) at org.apache.cocoon.sax.component.XSLTTransformer.setConfiguration(XSLTTransformer.java:205) at ......
```

block in cocoon:

```
  <map:pipeline>
    <map:match pattern="product">
<!--       <map:generate src="sample/p.xml"/> -->
      <map:generate src="https://productweb.com"/>
      <map:transform src="xsl/product.xsl" />
      <map:serialize type="xml"/>
    </map:match>
  </map:pipeline>
```

product.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <img>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </img>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="x:span[@class='prodImage']/x:img">
    <xxx>
      <value-of select="@src"/>
    </xxx>

  <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You show a 'product.xsl' and a Cocoon block referring to 'product.xsl', but your error message refers to 'productCard.xsl'.  Significant?

Comment: Is this your real code? Your `value-of` tag is not prefixed properly, although this should just cause the XSLT to not function correctly, rather than generating an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this kind of error doesn't appear for bad formatted XSLT file or for the syntax errors.

This is because of availability of XSLT file. Make sure that you have specified file name correctly. Try to access the file path you have specified from explorer or browser (This validates filepath as well as filename) .. Also file extension should be same as what you have specified. If you specify as `*.xsl` and actual file is `*.xslt` then it is not accessible.

Comment: I have reviewed the log of cocoon, nothing found. I checked the XSL file path.

I can not find it can be. Thank!.

Comment: without XSLT, serialize type "html". Error:
The entity "aacute" was referenced, but not declared.

Comment: @AntonMM, I am unaware of this.

Comment: I found it to java certificate problem. I'm doing this cocoon. Now the problem I have with cocoon. the beans Generate:html. Thanks for your interest.